# Return a list of user defined class type Scala

Tags: scala, list, indexing, functional-programming

I am trying to return a list of all the columns which are not full in below function. "isColumnFull" function will check if the list is full or not. GameState is a list of list. I am not sure where is the mistake. Could you please help?

```
type GameState = List[List[String]]

case class ColumnNum(index: Int)

val count = 0 //not sure this is needed
def allViableColumns(game: GameState): List[ColumnNum] = 
for((xs, count) <- game.zipWithIndex) yield {if(!isColumnFull(xs))List(count+1)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the indices of the columns:

```
type GameState = List[List[String]]
case class ColumnNum(index: Int)
def allViableColumns(game: GameState): List[ColumnNum] = 
  for((xs, i) <- game.zipWithIndex; if !isColumnFull(xs)) yield ColumnNum(i + 1)
```

If you want the columns, it's just:

```
def allViableColumns(game: GameState): List[List[String]] = 
  game filterNot isColumnFull
```

Should you decide to use the first version, consider changing `(i + 1)` to `i`: there are usually no good reasons for one-based indexing.